# Optimizing a code in SAS that recalculates a variable based in other variables

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that contains information on the consumption of a series of food items, basically, the frequency of consumption, the quantity consumed and if it is a food item that you consume sazonally or not. Also, some food items also have a type (say you consume either normal soda or diet soda, for an example). Each food item is named as "DIEA#" plus an letter(F for frequency, Q for quantity, S for sazonality and T for type (if needed)). The dataset looks something like this.

```
ID    DIEA1F    DIEA1Q    DIEA1S    DIEA1T    DIEA2F    DIEA2Q    DIEA2S    ...
1     3         20        0         1         1         10        0         ...
2     1         50        0         2         3         30        0         ...
3     5         10        1         2         1         15        0         ...
4     8         5         0         1         2         10        1         ...
...   ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
```

In another dataset, i have the nutritional information about each food item, using the frequency variable as an index

```
VARF      TYPE    CALORIES  FAT       VIT.A     VIT.B     ...
DIEA1F    1       150       20        8         0         ...
DIEA1F    2       120       5         7         0         ...
DIEA2F    .       50        0         3         25        ...
DIEA3F    .       67        5         1         10        ...
...     ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
```

So, i have around 15k respondants, 114 food items and 160 nutritional variables for each food item (more if that item has different types).
What i need is to calculate the total consumption of each nutritient for each person, based on the food consumption data.
I actually solved this problem, however, i think that my solution is way too slow. It takes around 5 hours to calculate.

Here is my code:

```
LIBNAME DIET "C:\Nutri\diet";

DATA diet.Test;
SET diet.qf2_die_100412;
    /*here is a list of nutrition variables, and i set each one to zero (exemple CAL=0;)*/
RUN;

PROC IMPORT OUT= diet.dadosdie DATAFILE= "C:\Nutri\diet\nutrifacts.xls" 
        DBMS=xls REPLACE;
 SHEET="plan1"; 
 GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;

DATA dadosdie;
SET diet.Dadosdie;
RUN;

%MACRO cnt_list(list=);
%LET i = 1;
%DO %WHILE (%CMPRES(%SCAN(&list., &i.)) ne );
%LET item&i. = %CMPRES(%SCAN(&list., &i.));
%LET i = %EVAL((&i. + 1);
%END;
%*** STORE THE COUNT OF THE NUMBER OF ITEMS IN A MACRO VARIABLE: &CNTITEM;
%LET cntitem = %EVAL((&i. - 1);
&cntitem.
%MEND cnt_list;

%MACRO NoType(food=);

%LET RootItem=DIEA&food.;

DATA diet.test;
        set diet.test;
        if &RootItem.F = 1 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 3;
        if &RootItem.F = 2 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 2.5;
        if &RootItem.F = 3 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 1;
        if &RootItem.F = 4 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0.8;
        if &RootItem.F = 5 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0.4;
        if &RootItem.F = 6 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0.1;
        if &RootItem.F = 7 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0.07;
        if &RootItem.F = 8 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0;
    RUN;

PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    SELECT Gramature INTO :gramature FROM dadosdie 
    WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" ;

    SELECT Grams_Ref INTO :gramsref FROM dadosdie 
    WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" ;

QUIT;

%LET listvarcomp= \* Here goes the same list of nutrition variables *\
%DO i=1 %TO %cnt_list(list=&listvarcomp.) ;
    %LET measure=%scan(&listvarcomp.,&i.);
    PROC SQL NOPRINT;
        SELECT &measure. INTO :parameter FROM dadosdie 
        WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" ;
    QUIT;
    DATA diet.test;
        set diet.test;
        if &RootItem.Q ne . and &RootItem.Q ne .P and &RootItem.S ne 1
        then &measure.= &measure. + (CONS_&RootItem.FPF*&gramature.*&parameter.*&RootItem.Q/&gramsref.);
    RUN;
%END;

%MEND NoType;   

%MACRO WithType(food=);

%LET RootItem=DIEA&food.;

DATA diet.test;
        set diet.test;
        if &RootItem.F = 1 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 3;
        if &RootItem.F = 2 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 2.5;
        if &RootItem.F = 3 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 1;
        if &RootItem.F = 4 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0.8;
        if &RootItem.F = 5 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0.4;
        if &RootItem.F = 6 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0.1;
        if &RootItem.F = 7 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0.07;
        if &RootItem.F = 8 then CONS_&RootItem.FPF = 0;
    RUN;

PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    SELECT gramature INTO :gramature FROM dadosdie 
    WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" ;

    SELECT Grams_Ref INTO :gramsref FROM dadosdie 
    WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" ;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :NOBStype FROM dadosdie            
    WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" ;

QUIT;

%LET listvarcomp= \* Here goes the same list of nutrition variables *\

%DO j=1 %TO &NOBStype. ;

    %DO i=1 %TO %cnt_list(list=&listvarcomp.) ;
        %LET measure=%scan(&listvarcomp.,&i.);
        PROC SQL NOPRINT;
            SELECT &measure. INTO :parameter FROM dadosdie 
            WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" AND TYPE = &j.;
        QUIT;
        DATA diet.test;
            set diet.test;
            if &RootItem.Q ne . and &RootItem.Q ne .P and &RootItem.S ne 1 and &RootItem.T = &j.
            then &measure.= &measure. + (CONS_&RootItem.FPF*&gramature.*&parameter.*&RootItem.Q/&gramsref.);
        RUN;
    %END;
%END;

%MEND WithType;
```

And then i apply the apropriate macro to each food item (for example %WithType(food=1))

I'm actually fairly new to SAS language, it's my second month working with it, so i guess i may be doing something redundant or not optimal in my code. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may need to break this problem down some. It's hard to find the time to sift through all the info you provided. Run the code in sections and find a part that is taking a long time...then post sample data along with the code that is slow...once we can run your code, inefficiencies will be much easier to diagnose. This problem might actually turn into multiple questions...then again someone may have the answer before I post this comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial anwswer I'll try and update it when I have more time ...

I think the best solution would be to use [hash tables](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/241-31.pdf) as lookup tables and then process all of your data in a single parse through the dataset.  This would probably reduce the time to < 1 minute.  It means you could avoid using macro variables as well.

Alternatively....

1) Think about adding indexes to your tables.

2) It also seems to me like this might be a could candidate for the use of the `SASFILE` statement.  It will allow you to load frequently queried datasets into memory so they can be accessed much faster.

3) The following code block

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    SELECT Gramature INTO :gramature FROM dadosdie 
    WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" ;

    SELECT Grams_Ref INTO :gramsref FROM dadosdie 
    WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" ;

QUIT;
```

Can be changed to:

```
PROC SQL NOPRINT;

    SELECT Gramature, Grams_Ref INTO :gramature, :gramsref FROM dadosdie 
    WHERE VARF = "&RootItem.F" ;

QUIT;
```

Which requires 1 less parse of the data.  There's a few places in the code that could benefit from this.

Finally - if you could post the log from running it for 1 food item that might help us identify the parts that could benefit the most from optimization.

Comment: +1 good thoughts... and hopefully that gets you up over 1.5k rep Rob ;)

Comment: Well, i did use some of your advices and my code did run faster, however, not as much as i did hope for. The hash idea i didn't fully understood yet, so i'll keep reading about it. Anyway, you did provide a series a good ideas, and for that i can't thank you enough.